# Is asking about how electrical/electronic things work off topic?

Tags: discussion

This question
[How do electric field wall dehumidifiers work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/576776/how-do-electric-field-wall-dehumidifiers-work)

was closed with the explanation "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."

I understand that the reasons for closing a question don't always match the options provided, and perhaps the people who voted to close had something different in mind, but the question is right there in the title: **how does this device work**, not "**how do you use this device**", and it's difficult to believe that the people who voted to close missed that.

So maybe some people think that questions about mechanisms are not about **design**, in which case questions like this one are off topic:
[Explain what is a transistor in plain English!](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14440/explain-what-is-a-transistor-in-plain-english)

... or maybe questions about how devices works are OK if the device is a transistor, but not if the device is a truck.  But that wouldn't explain closing a question about electro-osmotic effect.

... or maybe questions about devices that don't work are off topic?  If so, I thinks that is a bad criteria. Lots of electrical/electronic designs don't work: understanding how and why things don't work is an important part of the electrical/electronic design process.

What's it to be?  Was the question on topic, or if not, can we get some clarity on what exactly was off topic about it?

Comment: "Explain what are transistors.." - that question was from a decade ago when EESE was kicking off. Those kind of generic questions helped to build site reputation at that time and I don't know what were the policies back then. But surely it would have been closed as too broad, if somebody asked the same question today.

Answer (score 6):

I think there are a couple of problems with the question: [How do electric field wall dehumidifiers work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/576776/how-do-electric-field-wall-dehumidifiers-work) - the primary one being that *they don't work*.
Essentially you'd end up asking the answerer to prove a negative.

The next problem is that, even if they did work, *how* they work is much more of a [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) question than it is an Electronics one.

In my opinion, the only on-topic electronics question here would be if you've already opened up the device, discovered for example that the circuit overall does X (where X is something describable in electronic terms such as produces a voltage Y between points A & B), and then proceeds to ask how the circuit does that.